# while loop terminating after fetching some data

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I have written a procedure that creates a temporary table and executes a query by fetching the rows from the temporary table.I have around 13486 rows in the temporary table.But when i am calling the procedure i observed that the procedure is getting terminated after fetching 107 rows from the temporary table.Moreover i also observed that this value is not constant..Sometimes it is 107 the other time it is 114 and some other time it is just 100.Why this happens?Please need help?Somebody please..Here is my procedure.And i came to know that while loop will terminate for >1000 iterations.Please suggest me a method to overcome this.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `lookup`.`test` $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE `lookup`.`test` ()  
BEGIN

CREATE  TEMPORARY  TABLE  lookup.airportname(id  int  AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY(id))
AS (select distinct airport_id from lookup.airport);  
SET @num=0;  
SET @arpt=NULL;  
SELECT count(*) INTO @num FROM airportname;  
SET @i=0;  

while @i<@num do  
SELECT airport_id INTO @arpt FROM airportname WHERE id=@i;  
select @arpt,@i;    
set @i=@i+1;  
end while;  
END $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

I am using mysql query browser.Thank you.

Comment: how do you know it's terminated?

Comment: Output might be trimmed. Delete the select inside the loop and do the same select after the loop. Let's see if @i is 13487.

Comment: yea its 13486..how come it got trimmed.. :(

Comment: Are you sure the ids are consecutive and don't contain gaps?

Comment: yes i am pretty sure about that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert value into id Then it should not be auto_increment. - Remove auto_increment from table definition, it should work

Comment: I just want them to order so that i can fetch them one by one.Do u have any idea to fetch each row other than adding id?If so please guide me.Thank u

Comment: Using continue handler you can... i will paste one of my SP shorty.. in answer

Answer (score 0):

delimiter |

create procedure employee_select()

Begin

Declare empno,done int(9);

Declare emp_select Cursor for select emp_no from gross_salary ;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

Open emp_select;      // cursor opening

read_loop: loop    // start looping all the datas one by one

```
fetch emp_select into empno; // fetching the select value into variable empno
```

//note :variable name should not be same as columne name in select statement"

```
IF done THEN
   LEAVE read_loop;   // if no more rows, this makes it to leave the loop"
END IF;

//Enter the code you want do for each row 

 end loop;
```

close emp_select;

End |

delimiter ;

Comment: Is that applicable only for cursors?Or else can i use it for any method?

Comment: for looping records inside SP you have to use cursors...  continue handler is for any error handling.. (to continue to run the procedure/code even incase of error - Usage can be beyond cursor)